# How to achieve the exact powerlevel10k git prompt style in oh-my-posh?

Tags: windows, powershell, git, windows-terminal

I am very fond of the powerlevel10k git prompt with all its symbols. You can find the full list [here](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k#what-do-different-symbols-in-git-status-mean).

Here is a screenshot of the powerlevel10k git prompt for a git repository on branch 'stable' with one unstaged change and one stash entry:

[image]

I have to use a windows machine for my job and WSL is not an option since I need to manage the versions of SDKs in my windows OS, so I am currently using [oh-my-posh](https://ohmyposh.dev/). I am using the powerlevel10k theme so it looks right for the most part. However, I can't seem to configure the git prompt to look the same, no matter how I fiddle with the git module settings or posh-git.

Here is the oh-my-posh git prompt for the exact same repository in the same state:

[image]

So my question is: How can I achieve the exact same git prompt in oh-my-posh, with the same symbols, wording and spacing for all possible git statuses?

Comment: "However, I can't seem to configure the git prompt to look the same ..." - attach some screenshots to show the difference

Comment: Sorry for the delay, added screenshots

Answer (score 1):

I have installed [`posh-git`](https://dahlbyk.github.io/posh-git/) from [here](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/posh-git/1.0.0), [`oh-my-posh3`](https://github.com/JanDeDobbeleer/oh-my-posh) from [here](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/oh-my-posh/3.169.2), [MesloLGS NF fonts](https://github.com/Kudostoy0u/pwsh10k#prerequisites), then

```
Import-Module posh-git
Import-Module oh-my-posh
Set-PoshPrompt -Theme <path to a given .omp.json file>
```

and it worked perfectly for all `json` files I tried,
and all 4 `powerlevel10k*.omp.json` included.
It also worked ok with https://github.com/Kudostoy0u/pwsh10k

Comment: Sorry, I've added screenshots now. You're right it looks the same in most ways, but the way it displays git repository statuses is different. See the screenshots I've provided for an example.